# SQL Error: Row size too large for VARCHAR(20)

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying to create a column named "brand_slug" type VARCHAR(20), nullable, collation "utf8mb4_unicode_ci" and I'm getting the error:

> SQL Error: Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table
>   type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535.

The weird thing is that for some VARCHAR columns it allows me to make them up to 255, while for others only 50 or 75 and in this case not even table. All this happens in the same table.

I am using the InnoDB engine.

Comment: This error message sounds to me like adding the new column would make the entire _row_ size too large.  So, nothing wrong with `VARCHAR(20)`, so long as adding it would not cause the row to exceed 65K.

Comment: What can I do about this? I have a table with 115 columns and I was forced to make about a third of them TEXT because it wouldn't allow me to use VARCHAR anymore.

Comment: You can't do annything except making a extra table where you store the `VARCHAR()` columns and use a reference id to your other table.

Comment: Why do I think that something like `brand_slug` should really be `brand_id`, an integer value, that looks up information about the brand in a reference table?

Comment: I'm not using any other table. I was trying to keep things simple because it's a table for device specifications (phones for example), so I could probably only make an extra table to categorize them by brands. But I decided to use the "brand" and "brand_slug" in the same table. Do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Also check that you've actually sized the varchar() columns appropriately - I've seen postcodes stored as a varchar(255) where actually globally they're a max of 10 chars. It's the total maximum size of your varchar() columns along with your other columns which all added up count towards that 64k so size them accurately.

Comment: One table to store EVERYTHING is generally a bad way to go. Not only is it difficult to make changes (if you need to change a brand_slug you'll have to change every record that shares that brand_id, for instance). Furthermore you can't scale easily. Even now you are hitting a limit on how large a row can be. Definitely a redesign is in order here to fix your current problem and avoid a few new problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for InnoDB tables is usually to change the row format:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

There will still be a finite limit on the row size, but will be able to fit more VARCHAR/BLOB/TEXT columns into the row.

Before you can do this, you must have the following MySQL options in effect:

```
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table = ON
```

For more information, read the documentation:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-file-format.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format.html

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (without seeing `SHOW CREATE TABLE`) that you style of writing a schema has most of these flaws:

- Do not blindly use `(255)` on `VARCHARs`; use sensible limits.
- Do not have hundreds of strings in a single table.
- Consider 'normalizing' any strings that have a lot of repeated values.